# Instafeed access token authentication issue

Tags: instafeedjs

I am trying to get instafeed from http://instafeedjs.com/. I am using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awesome',
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});
feed.run();
</script>
```

But when debugging with firebug, its giving error: "Uncaught Error: Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved by following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 'xxxxx',
    accessToken: 'cccccccccc'
});
userFeed.run();
</script>
```